# Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\operatorname{Re}(z_n)=\operatorname{Re}(z)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Suppose $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }z_n=z$.
 Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\operatorname{Re}(z_n)=\operatorname{Re}(z)$

Where, $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $z_n$ is a complex-sequence.

**My work**

Let $\epsilon >0$,

By hypothesis exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $|z_n-z|<\epsilon.$

We know $|\operatorname{Re}(z_n)|<|z_n|$ and $|\operatorname{Re}(z)|<|z|$ then,

Then

$|\operatorname{Re}(z_n)-\operatorname{Re}(z)|\leq|\operatorname{Re}(z_n)|+|\operatorname{Re}(z)|<|z_n|+|z|$

Here i'm a little stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is\begin{align}\bigl\lvert\operatorname{Re}(z_n)-\operatorname{Re}(z)\bigr\rvert&=\bigl\lvert\operatorname{Re}(z_n-z)\bigr\rvert\\&\leqslant\lvert z_n-z\rvert\\&<\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.

Comment: Is there a typo? Is it $\operatorname{Re}(z_n)-\operatorname{Re}(z)$?

Comment: @Alex I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $|Re(w)| \leq  |w|$ is always true.... then apply it to $z_n - z$